# How to be able to display a p:slideMenu more than once if the p:commandLink trigger has an AJAX update and listener attribute?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menu

My current approach causes the `p:slideMenu` to be displayed only once, i.e. the first click of `menuTrigger` displays the menu, all further clicks (after it's been hidden the first time, e.g. by clicking on `menuHideLabel`) cause the menu to be not displayed:

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <p:commandLink id="menuTrigger"
            value="Open slide menu"
            style="background: #{backingBean0.background};">
        <p:ajax listener="#{backingBean0.listener0()}"
                update="menuTrigger"/>
    </p:commandLink>
    <p:slideMenu id="slideMenu"
            trigger="menuTrigger"
            overlay="true"
            triggerEvent="click"
            my="left top"
            at="left bottom"
            style="width:180px;">
        <p:menuitem id="menuItem1"
                value="Menu item 1"/>
    </p:slideMenu>
    <p:outputLabel id="menuHideLabel"
            value="Hide slide menu"/>
</h:form>
```

The backing bean with the listener which ought to be called if `menuTrigger` is clicked:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class BackingBean0 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String background = "";

    public void listener0() {
        System.out.println("listener0");
        background = "green";
    }

    public String getBackground() {
        return background;
    }

    public void setBackground(String background) {
        this.background = background;
    }
}
```

An SSCCE is provided at https://gitlab.com/krichter/primefaces-open-slide-menu-with-selenium with output of the reproduction of the problem with Arquillian at https://gitlab.com/krichter/primefaces-open-slide-menu-with-selenium/-/jobs/85986586. It doesn't contain more information that the MCVE above and can be used to facilitate the local investigation of the issue.

I'm using Primefaces 6.2.

Comment: i have verified your issue.  Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @Melloware reported at https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3921